How to serialize JSON string into JSON object for schema registry validation in confluent cloud SQS connector?
What I am trying to do:

Send data from my app(Ruby on rails) to SQS.
Create SQS Source Connector in Clonfluent Cloud to pull data from the queue.

I have a schema registry and I would like my messages to be checked against it before being saved.
It can work with the output record value format being set to JSON_SR
My problem is message formatting when pulling from SQS. I can only send a string to SQS as a message body, but I would need JSON. Currently, all messages in the body field are just string representations of JSON messages.
The data I send, serialized as JSON string, as SQS can't accept JSON in messageBody
{
      "username": "name",
      "property": "test prop",
      "created_utc_date": "2024-04-18T08:00:00Z"
}

when pulling from SQS value is filled with a lot of fields but we can use SMT to extract just "Body" where my message is. The extracted message is just a JSON string
"{\"username\":\"name\",\"property\":\"test prop\",\"created_utc_date\":\"2024-04-18T08:00:00Z\"}" 
and it can not be saved as I get an error.
"The connector has failed to register a new schema with Schema Registry because it is incompatible with an existing schema for the same subject."
I looked at a lot of possible solutions, SMT, converters, but I didn't manage to get anything to work, is there a way I can somehow deserialize that data at some point so it can be ingested by the connector?
The only thing I found was this https://www.confluent.io/hub/redhatinsights/expandjsonsmt/ but that plugin cannot be added to Confluent Cloud.

I am assuming you cannot read the string and parse it using JSON.parse?

Can you maybe post some code as to what you are doing/trying to do that results in that specific error? I am having a difficult time following along based on the post description

@dbugger No. The point at which this breaks is when SQS connector pulls data from SQS. At this point the data in the stream should be processed and JSON parsed, but I do not know how to do it. As said in questions, I tried SMT-s(but the ones I would need are not available in cloud), and setting up JSON converters, but it didn't work.

@engineersmnky There is no code to be shared as this is all infra setup. I Have an SQS queue that is producing messages, and SQS connector in the confluent cloud that is consuming them. The error I get I clear, as my data is not JSON formatted, but just a string. The problem, and the question is, how and where could I parse this JSON.
But it seems like this approach is not good, so I will probably completely change the architecture and not use SQS in the end.

Sounds like the json converters are the way to go -- all the connector info I stumbled across seemed to be working with json.

@dbugger yeah i did that, I set up converter as explained here [link]https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/), so I added value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter and it did nothing

Add updated information to the question -- don't bury it in comments.  Also don't expect people to follow links - show what you did in the question.

So I have not managed to do this. However, I did something similar.
Since I didn't find a way to get the message I wanted in the correct format to the correct topic in Kafka using the connector, I got rid of it and exchanged it for the AWS Lambda function.
AWS Lambda is now triggered by SQS. Using the lambda I can format, serialize and change my messages as much as I was before sending them to Kafka.
If anyone else will want to try and use this kind of solution here is my Lambda code


const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const { SchemaRegistry } = require('@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry');

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    const eventRecords = event.Records;
    await Promise.all(eventRecords.map(async (record) => {
        const message = JSON.parse(record.body);
        const topic = message.topic;
        await publishToKafka(message, topic);
    }));
}

publishToKafka = async function (message, kafkaTopic) {
    const kafkaBrokers = [process.env.KAFKA_DEV_CLUSTER];
    const schemaRegistryUrl = process.env.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL;

    const registry = new SchemaRegistry({
        host: schemaRegistryUrl,
        auth: {
          username: process.env.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEV_API_KEY,
          password: process.env.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEV_API_SECRET,
        },
      })
    // Just the way we name schemas
    const schemaName = kafkaTopic + '-value';
    const ssl = true;

    const kafka = new Kafka({
        brokers: kafkaBrokers,
        ssl,
        sasl: {
            mechanism: 'plain',
            username: process.env.KAFKA_DEV_API_KEY,
            password: process.env.KAFKA_DEV_API_SECRET,
        },
        securityProtocol: 'SASL_SSL'
    });

    const producer = kafka.producer();
    await producer.connect();

    try {
        const id = await registry.getLatestSchemaId(schemaName);
        const encodedPayload = await registry.encode(id, message)

        await producer.send({
            topic: kafkaTopic,
            messages: [{ value: encodedPayload }]
        });

        console.log('Message sent to Kafka');
        return 'Message sent to Kafka';
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message to Kafka:', error);
        return 'Error sending message to Kafka';
    } finally {
        await producer.disconnect();
    }
};



So in the end my workflow is pretty simple, send messages to SQS and than lambda function process those messages and send them into kafka.
